# Ajax Website does not load Google-Maps correctly

Tags: ajax, google-maps

I use an ajax plugin (smartAjax) for my website and on one of my pages, I have google map. All is working perfect without using ajax but as soon as I use google map in combination with ajax, google map does not load correctly anymore.

You can view here:
http://mark-i-mark.com/lab/eys/public/ajax1.html

All looks great but when clicking on "SCHEDULES & FEES" in the top menu and then clicking on "OUR CONCEPT", which suppose to bring you back to the map, the map does not appear anymore. If you refresh the page, you can see a short flash of it but it does not load correctly.

This is about the address, as shown in the address bar because if you delete the last part (#ajax1.html), the map appears correctly.

Does anybody have any idea what I may do wrong? I am happy about any suggestions.

cheers ;-)